# try FileInputStream and FileOutputSteam both throw exception

Tags: android, exception, fileinputstream

```
try {
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("p1");
pictureTaken.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and

```
        case R.id.open:
        ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im);
        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("p1");
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            byte[] bitMapA= new byte[buf.available()];
            buf.read(bitMapA);
            Bitmap bM = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapA, 0, bitMapA.length);
            im.setImageBitmap(bM);
            if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            }
            if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
```

Both try, but they don't pass in de-bug, they just got to the catch... I got most of these parts online and modified them to my needs, but even so, it all makes sense and works in my head. Just don't see why it throws the exception.

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like its on Android, and from the path you are using (`p1`) you are just trying to save to a file in the app's running folder. Broadly speaking you CAN NOT write to the whatever directory that is. You'll want to do something like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput ("p1", MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE);
```

in the first code block, and then:

```
FileInputStream in = openFileInput("p1");
```

in the second code block.

Comment: Femi is right, in Android - you'd need to use openFileInput/openFileOutput to get valid Stream objects.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was getting confused and mislead by the http://developer.android.com site, where they say that this is the way to save and open. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Wait, I have one more question, what if I want to save pictures and some other files to a folder that is public (can be seen when connected with usb). Do I still used input/output streams? Also, you save a picture by compressing, what are the other ways to write (audio, video, etc). Sorry, i'm just new to Android dev =p.

Comment: `openFileOutput` and `openFileInput` are specifically for content that is local to the app. If you want to save files that are on the USB card then you would use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder for an example of writing.

Comment: I have this from the link you told me to look at, and yet I still don't see the file...    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/myapp/photos");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");
try{
Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureTaken.getPath());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    byte b[] = bytes.toByteArray();
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    f.write(b);
    f.close();
   }
   catch...

Comment: Also, do you have to convert everything you want to save to a byte array first? and then turn it back when reading data?

Comment: You should just be able to do `bImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));`

Comment: wait, it doesn't like the Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureTaken.getPath()); in the debug. Is that why pictureTaken = data.getData();
ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
im.setImageURI(pictureTaken); doesn't work? It works if I use bitmap when gettingdata, but when I try Uri (so quality isn't lost) it doesn't work...

Comment: Not sure, never used the Uri.

Comment: well, how do you getData so that the picture is bigger than a tumbnail size?