# Problem with storing data in Android

Tags: android, save, android-edittext

I have a button which stores data written in the EditText form above it to internal memory, but for some reason the code doesn't work. It doesn't even display the toast message.

```
final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
final String Day = dayName;

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String FILEOUTPUT = Day;
                BufferedWriter bfw;

                try {
                    bfw = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter(FILEOUTPUT));
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(editData.getText().toString()));

                    bfw.write(scan.nextLine());
                    bfw.close();
                    Toast.makeText(ModifyInfo.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(ModifyInfo.this, "Save error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                }
            }
        });
```

> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341): Fail to save
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Monday (Read-only file system)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at 
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:94)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:66)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   java.io.FileWriter.(FileWriter.java:80)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   com.geft.timetable.ModifyInfo$2.onClick(ModifyInfo.java:77)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 07-19 20:00:59.677: ERROR/File Save(341):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Any exceptions in your logcat?

Comment: It doesn't show the toast, because you don't call `toast.show();` (you can probably chain that). I assume you're getting an error. Why not log your error, instead of catching it and just throw a generic error? At least use `e->getMessage()` in your `Toast`, but better just write it to the log.

Comment: Thanks! I got the Toast to show, but it keeps saying "Save error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you doing with this line is wrong probably `editData.getText().toString()`.If your editData is an EditText then your program will need a file name from it.I think you are not providing file name here.You are supposed to enter the string here that should be saved in the file.

Comment: I'm confused. Could you please give a short example on what I should have done?

Comment: Please see this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(editData.getText().toString()));This line don't have any file.Please see the answers of my previous comment's question how to write a file