# What is the proper way to dump a string into a text file?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have an issue that I'm stumped on.  I run a command to get back a list of items which can be as many as 25 entries. They are one word entries.

For example:
one
two
three
fourteen

I have this in a StringBuilder.

I need them to pipe into a text file on the devices external storage.  Right now my code is creating the folder and the file but the file is coming up blank.  I can dump the string to the Logcat so I know it's populated correctly.  The issue is the try/catch I have below.

```
 StringBuilder list = new StringBuilder();
 //stuff done here to get the string and check for external storage and set up the file       name and folder.

 String names = list.toString();
 try{
    FileOutputStream fout = new FilterOutputStream(file);
    OutputStreamWeriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(fout);
    output.write(names);
    output.close();
    fout.close();
   } catch (IOException e){
      }
```

Any help is great appreciated.  All my searching points me back to examples of code like I have here so I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a file in external storage in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

The [write()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28int%29) method that you are using is for writing a single character. In order to write the entire string use the [write()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) method intended for writing multiple characters instead - it requires you to give the length of the string to write, for your code this would be:

```
output.write(names,0,names.length());
```

Comment: Thanks but the file is coming up blank.

Comment: Have you tried writing a constant string? Just as a test to find out whether the problem is with the output steam or the string replace the `output.write(names)` with something like `output.write("test",0,4)`. Another option is to try using the [BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

Comment: Yes I have tried that.  A constant string works properly and the file is populated correctly with the string.

Comment: Clearly then your problem is with the way you build your string from the list, i.e. the `//stuff done here to get the string` part :) Since that code is not there I'm not sure what could be the issue.