# unable to create directory in external storage android

Tags: android

I have problem creating a directory,this the code that i'm using:

```
private void CreateDirectoryForPictures(){
    boolean res = isExternalStorageWritable();
    _dir = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "camerarealstate");
    if (!_dir.exists())
    {
        res = _dir.mkdir();
    }
}
```

also i have the following permission in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.realstatediary.jperera.realstatediary" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

the method isExternalStorageWritable return true, i have added to the emulator an external sdCard.
I don't know why i can't create the directory, i know this question is redundant in the forum but i check all the answers and i don't find the solution.
I will appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advanced
I don't have problem saving files, i have problem creating the directory, maybe is something about any configuration because as i know i don't have problem in the code, maybe someone had the same issue any time and could help me with any idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a file in external storage in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)

Comment: Is not the same, my problem is with the directories not to save the file, the problem is with the mkDir() method.

Comment: Did your try `_dir.mkdirs();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this method

```
res = _dir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a Similar problem, Somehow in the code:

```
 if (!_dir.exists())
{
    res = _dir.mkdir();
}
```

the body of loop doesn't get executed.

My advice is to try :

```
     File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myAppCache/");
     directory.mkdirs();
```

where `mkdirs()` creates parent directory.

Comment: thanks @oblivion i change mkdir() for mkdirs() and everything work fine!