# permission denied on creating new file in external storage

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I want to create a new file in external storage if that file doesn't exist already.
I've already read similar questions in SO and have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my manifest.
Testing on GenyMotion emulator with android 5.1 and xperia t with android 4.3 the result is same and I get "**open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**" on `file.createNewFile()`. I checked in runtime and `getExternalStorageState` functoin return value is "**MOUNTED"**.

**Note:** If I create the file manually, my code works perfectly and reads the content meaning that accessing to external storage is OK.
I although write to external storage another place in my code using `getExternalPublicStorage` for saving captured image and it works fine!

```
File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File config = new File(f, "poinila config" + ".txt");
if (!config.exists()) {
    if (!config.createNewFile()) {
        // toast that creating directory failed
    } else {
        writeDefaultIpPort();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** 
   path string is "/storage/sdcard0/poinila config.txt"

Comment: you check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)

Comment: 'If I create the file manually, my code works perfectly'  ??? Please explain 'manually' and what it has to do with your code.

Comment: 'Logger.toast("failed to create directory");'.  Directory???

Comment: @greenapps: By 'manually' I mean creating the file not through the app code. Like creating by file manager, or copy a existing file with same name into external storage directory.

Comment: Logger.toast("... Directory") was a gaffe! I will correct that.

Comment: `If I create the file manually, my code works perfectly' ??? Please explain  What has that to do with your code was the question.

Answer (score 2):

well I think this is the new security feature introduced in android. Runtime permissions. You have to do something like this

```
           int hasReadExternalStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if(hasReadExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setMessage("You need to Allow access to Images to set a Company Logo")
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    requestPermission();
                                }
                            }).show();
                    else
                        requestPermission();
            else
                callChooser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your permission is right place in manifest file as

```
  <application>
        ...

    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I double checked and yes permissions are in right place

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think it is a missing / in the path. Try this:

```
config = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +  "poinila config.txt" );
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Could you post the complete stack trace? Also the Path-String?

Comment: Strangly, the stacktrace isn't printed in console! But I will attach an image when catching exception in debug mode. Path string added to question

Comment: All the Exceptions `cause` fields as far as I saw were "libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Comment: I still thinks this is a path issue. Try it on /storage/emulated/0/. This should refer to the internal  "sd-card".

Comment: I've tried that (on both emulator and a real device) and result is the same

Comment: This is my stack trace: 09-10 16:09:51.668: W/System.err(10511): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0test.log: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: as you can see there is a missing /. I don't know why I can't add the / there. I think you should use the StreamReader/Writer method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android?lq=1