# Android Write file on sd card getting error : Open Failed eacces permission denied

Tags: java, android, file

I am trying to write an image file to sd card but i get an error :**Open Failed eacces permission denied**.

i am using this code:

```
File ff = new File(aa.datasearchSG_getter().get(0).getUrl()+ "try" );
try{ 
    ff.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e){ 
    Log.d("error" , "creating");
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

I have added permission :-

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but still getting error.

Comment: If you are executing this on android 6, I believe you have to get runtime permission for this

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854359/exception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android

Comment: No i am using android 5.1 for testing (real device)

Comment: where you put the <uses-permission> tag

Comment: And i have seen this post but no solution yet

Comment: I have tried putting it at starting before <application> tag and after </application> tag

Comment: I am able to write file to internal storage but not external

Comment: can you post the code where you try to write on external?

Comment: File ff = new File(aa.datasearchSG_getter().get(0).getUrl()+ "try" );
        try{
            ff.createNewFile();}
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("error" , "creating");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: aa.settergetter part of code is throwing this string :-  /storage/sdcard1/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0258.JPG

Comment: And I want to create file in the same folder. This code works perfect on internal storage file

Comment: add your complete code

Comment: try copying this code (obv editing the file names and operations) http://stackoverflow.com/a/8330635/4700782

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue. We need to get TreeUri using Android Storage Access Framework(SAF) and then using that Uri to modify the file.