# Android: Can't open existing file?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to read a file from the sdcard created by 3rd party app and I get an error:
`I/System.out: Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/export.csv: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`
I'm using Android Studio installing on a Asus Nexus 7 tablet running Marshmallow.

My manifest file includes:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test.imagechooser">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application....
```

and I added

```
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
```

to my MainActivity.java file.
Code for getting the file is:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"export.csv");
System.out.println(file.toString());
System.out.println(file.exists());
if (file.exists()) System.out.println(file.canRead());
checkExternalMedia();
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    ...
    br.close();
 }
 catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);
 }
```

The `checkExternalMedia` method is copied from [Write a file in external storage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android/8330635#8330635) and claims that read and write permission are set to true.  However, while my `file.exists()` returns true, `file.canRead()` returns false and the `BufferedReader` statement 
causes the `FileNotFoundException`.  Somebody suggested to disconnect from the PC or add a `/` to `export.csv` but none of that had any effect.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You did request the permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Thanks for the redirect.  I thought the Manifest.permission.READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would do the trick.