# How can I create a File in an accessible folder on Android? (non-root)

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm able to create a file using

```
File directory = cw.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 //directory.mkdirs();
 File backupDB = new File(directory, backupname);
```

I've also tried

```
 File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"images");
```

and

```
 File backupDB = new File(directory, backupname);
```

with no luck, this is the full method

```
   public String backUpDatabase(String backupname){

      try {
       File directory = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));
            File currentDB = new File(DBlocation);
            File folder = new File("/sdcard/exports/Database_Backups/");
            File backupDB = new File(directory, backupname);

            if (!(folder.exists() && folder.isDirectory())) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
            else{
                return "didnt work";
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          return "didnt work";
        }

        return backupname.toString();

    }
```

I've used the permissions yes.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I would just like to backup the database file to an accessible file that I can then see on the phone/computer itself.

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android it may help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write to external storage on android Lollipop and above you need to [request permission at run time.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Three methods are important here:

1. `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` to check if the permission is given
2. `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` to request if the permission not given
3. `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to perform the desired operation once the user gives the permission

[Refer to this answer for the code and details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150620/4726718)