# Write on Internal Storage

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to write in internal storage in Android? I tried the following from google developer site-

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);

String filename = "myfile";
String fileContents = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is that whenever I uninstalls the app the file is also deleted. However I am required to keep that file even after uninstalling the App...

Comment: that time you need to store file in external storage.

Comment: context.getFilesDir() returns your application dir "/data/data/your package/files". This folder is deleted when you uninstall your app. You should consider placing your files in other directory.

Comment: rerefer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You have to define which type of file you are try to create like.

FileType = "image";
   FileType = "text";

Define filetype in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `context.getFilesDir()` you're accessing the project files directory. If you want to save it externally, you should use something like `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` instead and use permissions in your Android Manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

You can look for other directories [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#fields).