# Saving file to storage programmatically

Tags: android, android-storage

I have tried with the following code:  (Previously it was working fine, Now I am testing its not working may be due to android 10 or some other error).

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    public class AboutUs extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
             new DownloadFile().execute("https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg");

        }


     private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, String> {
            private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

            @Override
            protected String  doInBackground(String... strings) {
                String fileUrl = strings[0];  
                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "MyFolder");
                folder.mkdir();

                File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileUrl);

                try{
                    pdfFile.createNewFile();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
                // presses the power button during download
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                        getClass().getName());
                mWakeLock.acquire();
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
                mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                mWakeLock.release();
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (result != null)
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
        }
        public static class FileDownloader {
            private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

            public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
                try {

                    URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
                    int bufferLength = 0;
                    while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    }
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

I have tried with the above code. 
I have added WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE and also ask run time permission

Comment: What kind of error are you getting now?

Comment: unable to save file to storage....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write a file in external storage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)

Comment: I mean is there any error coming on logcat while saving file?

Comment: No I am not getting any error message

Comment: `may be due to android 10 `. Indeed. Because of Android 10.

Comment: `folder.mkdir();` If you would call mkdirs() only when the directory did not exist yet and then check the return value you would know that the directory was not created.

Comment: You should care for the folder before you call your async task.

Comment: is pdfFile.createNewFile(); creating the empty image file in the desired directory?

Comment: Impossible as the directory does not exist. Not on Q.

Comment: In android 10, `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `/sdcard/Android/data/your app package name/` as external storage and your file will store in this path. Did you check this path?

Comment: Instead of all the "Please do the needful"s and other fluff, please explain the problem clearly / ask a clear question

Answer (score 0):

There were major changes on how files can be accessed on Android 10

See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

You need to use MediaStore or Storage Access Framework (SAF), details https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared for files outside of your App's private directories.

As you are storing photo then MediaStore would be the way to access pictures https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Though as a quick fix is to temporarily opt out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility but this will only work until Android 11

Some better examples at https://proandroiddev.com/working-with-scoped-storage-8a7e7cafea3

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 requered `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in your `AndroidManifest` file

check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx.xxxx">

  <application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Take into account that this solution will not work in the future Android 11.