# Unable to save file to an external storage directory in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-external-storage

**I have looked at all of the questions related to saving a file in the external storage.**

Links:

- [Write a file in external storage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)
- [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)

I even copied the entire method for the same but still cannot get the same result. Here is the log I am getting for the same:

`W/System.err: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`

`W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)`

**code:**

```
public void saveImageBitmap(Bitmap image_bitmap, String image_name) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root, "/memories");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            myDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String fname = "Image-" + image_name + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        Log.d(TAG, "File file: " + file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            file.createNewFile(); // if file already exists will do nothing
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            image_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.toString()}, new String[]{file.getName()}, null);
    }
```

Comment: which android version do you use? Q/10 or a older one?

Comment: On the emulator, I use API 29

Comment: does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

there are a few changes with storing data to media folder since android 10 (Q).the easiest way is to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest under application, but it is more like a work around.

search for "store image android 10" here and you find the right way for you.