# unable to create directory in external storage

Tags: android, directory, save, storage, store

I wanted to the application to create a new directory to store downloaded image inside sdcard. I tried a few methods but still I can't seems to get it work. I included permission for External Storage in android manifest as well. Any comments will be appreciated.

```
        Bitmap bm = null;
        InputStream in;
            in = new java.net.URL("http://blogs.computerworld.com/sites/computerworld.com/files/u177/google-nexus-4.jpg").openStream();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(in));
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/map");
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "Image"+NumIncrease);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

Below is what I get from running this.

```
12-05 15:55:25.566: D/skia(4244): ---- read threw an exception
12-05 15:55:25.585: D/skia(4244): ---- read threw an exception
12-05 15:55:25.585: W/System.err(4244): java.io.IOException: Is a directory
12-05 15:55:25.585: W/System.err(4244):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.read(Native Method)
12-05 15:55:25.585: W/System.err(4244):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:165)
12-05 15:55:25.585: W/System.err(4244):     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:290)
12-05 15:55:25.585: W/System.err(4244):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:166)
12-05 15:55:25.863: E/MediaStore(4244): Failed to create thumbnail, removing original
```

**EDIT**
Below is how I handle the bitmap.

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fos);
```

Comment: what about extension (.jpg, .bmp)?

Comment: look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741

Comment: can we see how do you write down the bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

Following points may help you

- Probably exception is thrown because there is no MediaCard subdir.
  You should check if all dirs in the path exist.
- Add the permissions in the manifest for this to work..
- You should never use "/sdcard/" as a constant, because manufacturers
  may decide to mount the SD-Card to another path. Always use
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); instead.

Further reading

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
- [Android saving file to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887078/android-saving-file-to-external-storage)
- [Android write to sd card folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder)