# file is not creating on SDCARD android

Tags: java, android

Hi i have below code for write file, that read a and b file and put data in ab.xml file

```
   String filePath1 = "/sdcard/Dictionarys/a.txt";
String filePath2 = "/sdcard/Dictionarys/b.txt";
String filePath3 = "/sdcard/Dictionarys/ab.xml";


        try {

        File file = new File(filePath3);
        file.createNewFile();

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(filePath1), UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);

        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(filePath2), UTF8), BUFFER_SIZE);
        FileOutputStream file3 = new FileOutputStream(filePath3);
        OutputStreamWriter out3 = new OutputStreamWriter(file3,UTF8);
        BufferedWriter br3 = new BufferedWriter(out3, BUFFER_SIZE);

        String sCurrentLine1, sCurrentLine2;

        while ((sCurrentLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null && ((sCurrentLine2 = br2.readLine())!=null)) {
            String s3 = sCurrentLine2.substring(sCurrentLine1.length());
            br3.write("<abcd abc=\""+sCurrentLine1+"\" def=\""+s3.trim()+"\"/> \n");
            br3.flush();
            i++;
        }
        br3.write("<data>\n");
        br3.flush();
        br3.close();
        out3.flush();
        out3.close();
        file3.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but xml file is not created on SDCARD path..

Comment: have you given permission to Write External Storage? It can be easy to overlook sometimes, or else  try following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Comment: Please try not to use hard coded sdcard path. Because in some devices the sdcard path can be /mnt/sdcard0/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting Path this way:

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Sometimes string path doesn't work and make sure you have following permissions added in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Note that the documentation for [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) indicates you should not use this method directly, but use `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)` instead

Answer (score 1):

First, **you shouldn't hardcode path** to the sdcard, as it can change from phone to phone.
Use method like `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)` instead.

Second, some filesystems have **buffering**. You should use the `fsync` method to make the actual write occurs. See [Saving Data Safely](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2010/12/saving-data-safely.html) for more information.

Comment: I upvoted your question because I do not feel it deserved the downvote,  but it is not really a good practice to ask for this... You should also accept Usama Sarwar answer if it helped you