# How to create and/or append to a file on android?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, filewriter

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    static void writeToFile(String text) {
    try {
        synchronized (fileLock) {
            File external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String sdcardPath = external.getPath();
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(sdcardPath
                    + "/Documents/myfile.txt", true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);

            out.write(text);

            out.close();
            filewriter.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.d("failed to save file", e.toString());
    }
}
```

On open file I get following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Documents/myfile.txt: 
    open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

1. The directory `/mnt/sdcard/Documents/` exists according to Root Browres
2. The application manifest does contain `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
3. `myfile.txt` does not exist, I want it created or appended

How do I create or append to a file on android?

**UPDATE**
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mytest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: when you print `sdcardPath` does it say `/mnt/sdcard/` ?

Answer (score 3):

first you have to create the file then append to it this is the code to create the file

```
    sFileName = "Android.txt";
    File root=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File textfile = new File(root, sFileName);
    textfile.createNewFile();
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but than I can't find the file later on in my file system. I should had created `/mnt/sdcard/myfile.txt`, but it's not there

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:

```
static void writeToFile(String text) {
    try {
        synchronized (fileLock) {
            File external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String sdcardPath = external.getPath();
            File file = new File(sdcardPath + "/Documents/myfile.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);

            out.write(text);

            out.close();
            filewriter.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        android.util.Log.d("failed to save file", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the exception in the method `file.createNewFile()`

Comment: I had the same exception because I don't have a `Documents` folder. Can you try to write `myfile.txt` directly at the root of the sdcard ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        File storagePath = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + "/dirname/");
        storagePath.mkdirs();
        File myFile = new File(storagePath, fileName);
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                myFile));
        try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

        } finally {
            try {
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
   File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 


   // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

   File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
   dir.mkdirs();
   File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

   try {
       FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
       PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
       pw.println("Hi , How are you");
       pw.println("Hello");
       pw.flush();
       pw.close();
       f.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

---

**OR:**

```
     File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppFolder/");

     File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppFolder/myFile.txt");        
     if(!direct.exists())
     {
         direct.mkdir();
     }        

     if (!file.exists()) {
             try {
                 file.createNewFile();
                 FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
                 PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
                 pw.println("Hi , How are you");
                 pw.println("Hello");
                 pw.flush();
                 pw.close();
                 f.close();

             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the code executes without exceptions, but the files don't appear in the filesystem

Comment: @ArsenZahray its working for me.are you checking in emulator or device?to see the file in emulator go to File Explore-->mnt-->sdcard-->download---->myData.txt.

Comment: The app says that the file was created, and that the directory exists, but Root Browser or file explorer or console emulator can't find those. very strange ((