# Saving changes of xml

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, save, runtime

I have an application that can edit the content of a XMl, pictures text audio, my problem is every time i exit the apps the content backs to its default value. Is there anyway to save the changes xml through runtime?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a lot of context missing in your question. What solutions have you tried? Where are you reading the XMI from? Have you tried saving the XMI to disk after it's been edited? If possible, please share the relevant code.

Comment: Well i try to find any codes before but I don't have any luck. I am reading the xml file from the apps and planning of transferring it to sd card, if it is possible. I don't have any idea for the codes i am searching for just simple reassigning of image and text that's all.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "reading the xml file from the apps". Please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder) for an example of saving to external storage (e.g., SD card).