# How to write json object in json file in sdcard in android

Tags: android, file-io, json

**How can I save a `json object` in a file in sdcard?**

Comment: get a string representation via `jsonObject.toString()` and write it to the file like there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get a String from the JSONObject and write it into the file like this:

```
String content = json.toString();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("path");
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(content);
bw.close();
```

You will of course need to catch/throw exceptions and so on.