# Copy files to google glass

Tags: file-permissions, google-glass, google-gdk, android-permissions

My google glass does not allow me to write or copy any file to its root folder (and do allow to the inner ones) - seems like a permissions problem.
Moreover, when trying to run some .bat or .exe file - it also does not work.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

> My google glass does not allow me to write or copy any file to its root folder (and do allow to the inner ones) - seems like a permissions problem.

That's normal. For security reasons, you are not allowed to copy a file to some paths such as system partition (unless you have the right permission).

You can check ownership and permission by using adb and ls command.

```
ls -l
```

[image]

Here's my root directory:

```
$ adb shell ls -l /
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2014-09-28 07:33 acct
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2014-09-27 00:24 cache
-rwxr-x--- root     root       264108 1969-12-31 19:00 charger
dr-x------ root     root              2014-09-28 07:33 config
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2014-09-28 07:33 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x system   system            2014-09-13 14:23 data
-rw-r--r-- root     root          116 1969-12-31 19:00 default.prop
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2014-09-28 07:33 dev
```

Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions

> Moreover, when trying to run some .bat or .exe file - it also does not
>   work. Is there a way to solve this issue?

.bat and .exe are for Windows but GLASS is Android (Linux base) so you cannot run those types of file on GLASS.

> [.bat: The first filename extension used by Microsoft for batch files.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file)
>
> [.exe is a common filename extension denoting an executable file (the main execution point of a computer program) for DOS, OpenVMS, Microsoft Windows, Symbian or OS/2.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe)

*Note: If you are making an app (glassware) that can write a file to sdcard. You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder):*

```
// get the path to sdcard
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// to this path add a new directory path
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + “/your-dir-name/”);
// create this directory if not already created
dir.mkdir();
// create the file in which we will write the contents
File file = new File(dir, “My-File-Name.txt”);
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = “This is the content of my file”;
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();

// In the manifest
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what I would like to do is this: after taking several photos and videos with the Glass, the files are stored in the glass memory. I would like to have some file (like bat script or something else) that will do the following: when I connect the USB and run some file, it automatically rename the files (photos, videos) in an increasing order and upload it to an ftp server. Is there a way to do that? (even via an android code)

Comment: @user2517096 sorry, i haven't tried ftb with Glass so i'm not sure but you can copy files to your local machine using adb e.g. adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera Camera