# How to Store a File in our sd card that we have inserted

Tags: android, storage, external, android-sdcard

I am trying to save a file in my External SDcard but the file is getting stored in internal storage. How to store the file in the SDcard inserted

```
mr = new MediaRecorder();
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
    Log.e("aa","sss");
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Recorder");
} else {
    cameraFolder= getDir("Recorder",MODE_PRIVATE);
}

if(!cameraFolder.exists()) {
    cameraFolder.mkdir();
}

fname = cameraFolder + "/myrec1.MPEG_4";
```

Comment: Your problem is how to find out the path to a removeble micro SD card. You know how to write a file once you have a path i think.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder), you can also find more detailed information on the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

As suggested in a comment below I'll improve this answer.

In order to save a file to a specific position in your SD card you need to create a File object which points to that position:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/your/file/directory");
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, "filename");
```

and then use a `FileOutputStream` to write the content.

Remember that you need to add the required permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: A sample program to write a file to SD card can be found at: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Comment: the file gets save to a path  when we use get External Storage method                                                        /storage/emulated/0/    but i want to save my file at location /storage/