# Can't create application directory on SD card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I'm developing an app that should store photos on SD card. First the SD card path is retrieved in the code, since *getExternalStorageDirectory()* doesn't return the accurate SD card path.
Then I'm trying to create a directory to store the pictures:

```
String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.example.me.sdapp";
// sdpath = "/storage/extSdCard/"
String path = sdpath+"Android/data/"+PACKAGE_NAME;
File folder = new File(path);
if (!folder.exists()){
   var = folder.mkdirs();
   if (!folder.canWrite()){
       Log.d("SD Card app", "Directory is not writable");
   }
}
```

The directory is not built and the log message does appear. Hence I guess I can't write to that space.
However, I can create manually the directory when I run with adb shell:

```
mkdir /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.example.me.sdapp
```

And after creating the directory manually, the pictures can be stored in it from the app.

Why can't I create my application folder on the SD card from the app, and yet once the folder has been created manually, I can still write files to it from the app? And how could I achieve creating that folder from the application?

I have tried to make it work with and without the permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE>
```

But I guess that wouldn't be the problem anyway since as soon as I manually create the directory, the app is able to write in it.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab III and Android version is 4.4.2.

**EDIT**

As some people marked my question as duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder), I will try to explain why that other post doesn't address my issue.

- All the answers refer to the method `getExternalStorageDirectory()` which **does not** always point to SD card; in my case, it points to internal storage. Hence when I use this method, I can indeed create my app folder from the application, but the folder will be created in internal storage and not on SD card.
- Some answers mention the manifest permission, which I said I have taken into account already.

Comment: `I just can't get it to work!`. To me it's very unclear what your problem is and what you want. And i see no question.

Comment: You're totally right. I'm rephrasing that asap.

Answer (score 0):

**For Path retrieving  **

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Your folder path" );
       if (!direct.exists()) {
                              mkdir();
                                         }
```

This will give you correct path of your sdcard.

Comment: As I told, _Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()_ doesn't return the SD card path but `/storage/emulated/0`, which is internal storage for my device. You can read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location) that explains the fact that the method does not always return SD card location. Anyway, AFAIK retrieving the path is not really the problem.

Comment: `This will give you correct path of your sdcard.`. No. This will never give the path to an SD card. Maybe on Android 2.2. But not later. I wonder who upvoted you.