# Save in Internal or External Storage?

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I am building an app which requires pictures from camera and gallery from a drop down. I want if the user selects camera option, the image gets saved in this file path -

```
Android/data/my_pkg_name(com.joey.imageapp)/files/user_avatars/file_name.png.
```

How do I create the file path and save the image there? Is internal or external storage the best place to store app-images? Thanks.

Comment: you can have a nice answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Answer (score 0):

use the following code for setting the path and launching camera

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri imageuri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/your path/yourfilename.png"));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageuri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks bro, that might work. I have checked my phone's file explorer and the package name of my app is present. I want to save in that folder, will this work?

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about image from gallery, how can I save in same path?

Comment: Image from gallery is already saved in your phone.Why you want to save again?

Comment: Bro, it's throwing a FileUriExposedException. How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Is internal or external storage the best place to store app-images?

**Internal Storage:**

> Files saved to the internal storage are private to your application
>   and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the
>   user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

**External Storage:**

> Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be
>   modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer
>   files on a computer.
>   [Data Storage in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

[Save the image to internal directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17674787/5188929)