# Could not find method StartRec(View) in a parent or ancestor Context

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error message when I run my android program and was wondering if anyone knew how to fix it...

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method StartRec(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            LocationManager locationManager;


            public void StartRec(View view, int[] grantResults) {



                    // Find the root of the external storage.
                    // See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-  storage.html#filesExternal

                    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


                    // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

                    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }




                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);


                }


            }


            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


                // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

                File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
                File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                ArrayList<Location> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(location);
                GPX.writePath(file,"hello",list);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }

        };


    public void stopRec(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Statistics.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined your method as:

```
public void StartRec(View view, int[] grantResults)
```

However, it seems as if you also are trying to use this method as a callback to a view click.

When called like this however, the method signature should only have a single argument, the View, ex:

```
public void StartRec(View view)
```

When the user clicks the button, only the view is known, the UI does not know how to populate the integer array that your method expects, find a different way of getting this data into the method.