# Create a folder and put json inside at install apk

Tags: java, android, json

I want to create a folder inside sdcard storage from the phone and put inside 3 `JSON` that i created before after install the apk.
How i can do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551821/android-write-to-sd-card-folder

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything on application install, as that process is done by Android itself and your app is not executing at any point.  What you can do instead is this. When your app starts, you check some - if it is not set, then you create these files and then set the flag, otherwise you assume that the app has run already and these files were created. You can use any facility you wan to store this flag - share preferences, internal storage or even using some API on the internet - it's up to you.

Alternatively, just check whether the files exist on the startup of your app and, if not, create them.